# Ruby: printing one attribute of user model for each user

Tags: ruby

I have a bunch of users in my database with these attributes, however, I only want the email address for each user

```
#<User id: 1, email: "email@yahoo.com", encrypted_password: "", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: "2012-09-03 09:14:01", updated_at: "2012-09-03 09:14:01", name: nil, confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: nil, confirmation_sent_at: nil, unconfirmed_email: nil, opt_in: nil, invitation_token: nil, invitation_sent_at: nil, invitation_accepted_at: nil, invitation_limit: nil, invited_by_id: nil, invited_by_type: nil>,
```

In the console, I did

```
  u = User.all
```

which printed all the users and their attributes.

Now, to get the email address for each i tried

```
   u.each do |f|
     f.email
   end
```

but it just printed the whole list of users again, with all their attributes.

Can anyone show me how to print a list of email addresses for all the users, leaving out the other attributes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your console will print at the end the result of what you typed.

So if you write u.each { anything }, the console will print the result of the each loop. To print stuff explicitly, you need to use output function (puts, p, pp, print etc)

```
users = User.all
puts users.map(&:email).join("\n")
```

Comment: thanks, can you please tell me what that's called, so I can read up on it. i.e. what is it that you're passing to map(&:email). I don't see it in the docs for map http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-map

Comment: This is Symbol#to_proc method. http://blog.thoughtfolder.com/2008-02-25-a-detailed-explanation-of-ruby-s-symbol-to-proc.html

Comment: This answer is totally correct, but I don't think it really addresses the OP's problem, which is that they don't understand what the REPL is outputting. The real help here is the `puts` statement, which is similar to `print` in other languages - it outputs the given value to the screen. What the OP was doing is simply accessing the `email` attribute for each user and not doing anything with it. The REPL (console) then outputs the result of the most recent statement, which is in fact the result of the call to `each`, not the contents of the block provided to it.